# going through text, parsing links

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have text that contains links (these are images links)
I need to parse the text so that I build it and when a link is envountered, the image is fetched.

so for example:

> "I once had a fox **`http://mysite.com/images/fox.jpg`**.
>   I also owned a little dog **`http://mysite.com/images/dog.jpg`**"

So that it whould look like this:

> **I once had a fox**

```
----------------------------------
|                                |
|Fox Image From                  |
|http://mysite.com/images/fox.jpg|
|                                |
|                                |
----------------------------------
```

> **I also owned a little dog and a rooster**

```
----------------------------------
|                                |
|dog Image From                  |
|http://mysite.com/images/dog.jpg|
|                                |
|                                |
----------------------------------
--------------------------------------
|                                    |
|rooster Image From                  |
|http://mysite.com/images/rooster.jpg|
|                                    |
|                                    |
--------------------------------------
```

What can I use to achieve this goal?

I already have the view set up, but now it only shows my text.
How can I add the images to that view? 
How do I parse them?
What's the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could feasibly use a `UIWebView` to display your text, and wherever a valid image link is found, wrap it in `<img>` tags.

To parse those links, you could use RegEx. You may need to tweak the regex yourself to your exact specs, but the rough jist would be `http(?:s)?://.+\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)`. That would pick up a weblink starting with http or https, and ending in .jpg, .png etc...(*untested by the way*)

In code, you could have it as

```
NSString *regExpString = @"http(?:s)?://.+\\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)";
NSString *storyStr = @"...";    

NSRegularExpression *storyRegex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:regExpString
                                                                      options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                        error:nil];

NSString* webViewStr = [storyRegex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:storyStr options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, storyStr.length) withTemplate:@"<br\><img src=\"$0\"></img><br\>"];
```

Then, use `webViewStr` within a `UIWebView`

```
UIWebView* webView = ...;
[webView loadHTMLString:webViewStr baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert this into HTML by wrapping the image links in `img src=` tags whenever you detect an image link (by using `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString: withString:` most probably).

So you convert all links from:

```
http://mysite.com/images/rooster.jpg
```

to

```
<img src="http://mysite.com/images/rooster.jpg">
```

Once you have the HTML, you can load it into a `UIWebView`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

We can write html code and show in textview

```
NSString *regExpString = @"http(?:s)?://.+\\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)";
NSString *yourStr = @"Test Article with Image and LinksTest Article with Image and Links http://image.gif";
NSRegularExpression *storyRegex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:regExpString options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

NSString* tempStr = [storyRegex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:yourStr options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, storyStr.length) withTemplate:@"<br\><img src=\"$0\"></img><br\>"];
NSString *htmlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> %@ </html>",tempStr];
[self.txtView setValue:htmlStr forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];
```